# Выбор нескольких значений из справочника и суммирование их и запись в другой справочник

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте. Делаю задание создание конфигурации "Ресторан" в 1С:Предприятие 7.7
В 1с новичек. 
Возник вопрос, каким способом можно реализовать следующее: есть справочник "Блюда" (в нем указывается название блюда, стоимость, ингредиенты) , он подчинен справочнику "Меню" (содержит списки меню по группам). Есть документ "ОформитьЗаказ" в нем надо как то  сделать так чтобы можно было выбирать несколько блюд из справочника, подсчитывать общую  стоимость стоимость и записать в справочник "Заказы" сумму заказа и имена всех блюд.

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего это можно реализовать, а то я только знаю как один элемент из справочника выбирать (можно конечно сделать много много полей для выбора блюд, но это как то не хорошо)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В табличную часть заполняйте список блюд. Создайте в ней блюдо, цену, количество...

Справочника Заказы быть не должно. Это неверно идеологически. Заказы - это документы должны быть, с датой, номером, с процедурой проведения (резервирование там будет и т.д.)...